# git .gitignore not ignore all my files

Tags: git, file

I have a problem with my .gitignore

here there my .gitignore content:

```
application/configs/application.ini
cache/
uploads/
thumbs/
docs/
.htaccess
*.swp
*~
nbproject/
```

it works for all of them except application/configs/application.ini

I can't understand why

Can you please help me

Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe application.ini has been already added to the repository? gitignore doesn't affect it in this case.

Comment: yes application.ini is added to the repository is there a way to ignore it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*application/configs/application.ini* is probably already tracked.
You need to remove it from your repo in order to be ignored in the future: `git rm --cached application/configs/application.ini`.

Comment: I don't want to remove it from the repo, I just want to don't push my application.ini and don't change my application.ini when I pull, is it possile ?

Comment: No you can't. What you can do though is having a versionned *application.ini-dist* file with a default configuration, and each time you clone the project, you *cp application.ini{-dist,}* and use the normal *.ini* which is ignored by Git.